# Show/Hide div dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a dropdown menu like the one over at https://www.nakedcph.com/. My current idea is to make a menu where the links display different divs on hover that is placed below the current menu and will work as a dropdown

```html
    <div id="menu">
 <ul>
 <li id="newarrivals-trigger"><a href="url">New Arrivals</a></li>
 <li><a href="url">Brands</a></li>
 <li><a href="url">Accessories</a></li>
 <li><a href="url">Journal</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

where #newarrivals-trigger displays this below

```html
<div id="dropdown">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
<li><a href="#">New Balance</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Puma</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Vans</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Y3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Reebook</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

using

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#newarrivals-trigger").hover(function(){
$("#dropdown").show();
}, function(){
$("#dropdown").hide();
});
});
</script>
```

My issue here is that when I remove my cursor from id="newarrivals-trigger" link the dropdown div disappears instantly.

How to construct this kind of dropdown (Nakedchp)?

[image: dropdown]

I can only seem to find ones where a link displays a row of links under it, like this.

[image: dropdown]

Any ideas, or knowledge of existing menus that could be used? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the source for the website your referenced to see if you can figure out what's keeping it open? Dumb question I know, but I have to ask.

Comment: Yeah I can't seem to figure out how it is put together.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this without the scripts.  With CSS, you can manipulate specific elements upon mousehover.  I would try creating the menu as a separate element with

```
.menuDiv{
  display:none;
}
```

Then, when you hover over the link that you want to trigger, you can activate the menu with

```
link:hover .menuDiv{
  display:block;
}
```

You might also want to add

```
.menuDiv:hover{
  display:block;
}
```

In order to keep the menu from disappearing when your mouse leaves the link.

Alternatively, using your code, try this out:

```
$("#newarrivals-trigger").on("mouseenter", function(){

    $("#dropdown").show();

});

$("#dropdown").on("mouseout", function(){

   $("#dropdown").hide();

});
```

This handles the mouse hover and mouse exit events separately, which should help solve your problem.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi!  
#dropdown{
 display: none;
}

#newarrivals-trigger:hover #dropdown{
  display:block;
}
does not seem to have any effect. The script <script>
$("#newarrivals-trigger").on("mouseenter", function(){

    $("#dropdown").show();

});

$("#dropdown").on("mouseout", function(){

   $("#dropdown").hide();

}); 
</script> do not display the dropdown either. Thanks though

Comment: Did you include my jQuery within your document.ready function? ...This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with jquery then you can use the belowcode. It shows a snippet of just one part of your menu working.

```js
$("#BrandsAll").hover(function() {
  $("#BrandDropdown").toggleClass("show","hide");
});
```

```css
#BrandDropdown{display:none;}
#BrandDropdown.show{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul id="newarrivalsTrigger">
    <li>New Arrivals</li>
    <li id=BrandsAll>Brands
    <ul id="BrandDropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Balance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Puma</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
    <li>Accessories</li>
    <li>Journal</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good suggestion but I need the brands to be displayed below the ="menu" itself. Like I showed on the example above where "Bags and Purses", "Electronics" etc are displayed below the menu triggered by the "Accessories"-link

Comment: You have not provided an CSS to go with. Update your initial code to add that in and i can change my answer accordingly.

Comment: What I mean is that I need <ul id="BrandDropdown">Links</ul> to appear beneath/outside <ul id="newarrivalsTrigger">Links</ul> not from within. Like shown in Nakedcph example.

Comment: Like I said do you have CSS for your dropdown? If yes paste it in

Comment: If you make all Li the same size in CSS and child ul the same size then you dropdown will work. The original question was for the functionality and does not contain any CSS to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably put the drop-down list inside the `<li>` of the list title.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="newarrivals-trigger"><a href="url">New Arrivals</a>
      <div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New Balance</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Puma</a></li>
        </ul>
        ...
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="url">Brands</a></li>
    <li><a href="url">Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="url">Journal</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And have the `#dropdown` div start out with a class that sets `display: none`.

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Then have the hover trigger remove/add the class instead of using show/hide. That way, as long as the mouse stays over the list title or the dropdown list, it's still hovering over the top-level `li`.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newarrivals-trigger").hover(function(){
      $("#dropdown").removeClass("hidden");
    }, function(){
      $("#dropdown").addClass("hidden");
    });
  });
</script>
```

You'd have to do a little more with the CSS to get the dropdown to be positioned correctly, but I assume you've already got that somewhere.

Comment: Thank you this seems to work but this the id="dropdown" disappears the second I remove my cursor from id="newarrivals-trigger" so I can't access the dropdown

Comment: It's probably a CSS problem. You'll need to make sure the dropdown div and the target element are immediately adjacent (or even overlapping). Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/9nogeccy/4

Answer (score 0):

By default use display none on your dropdown then show it using display:block when menus are hovered

```js
$('li').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('ul li div.hover').removeClass('active');
  var submenu = $(this).children()[1];
  $(submenu).addClass('active');
});
$('ul li div.hover').on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
li{
display: inline-block;
}
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  display: none;
}
.hover.active{
display: block;
}
.hover1:hover > .hover {
  display: block;
}
.hover2:hover > .hover {
  display: block;
}
.hover3:hover > .hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hover1">
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <div class="hover">dropdown menu1</div>
 </li>
 <li class="hover2"><a href="">Link</a>
  <div class="hover">dropdown menu2</div>
 </li>
 <li class="hover3">
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <div class="hover">dropdown menu3</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good idea, but "hover1-2-3" disappears the second you remove the cursor from "Link" so they can't be used.

Comment: @Maren I've updated now my answer added some jquery on it

Answer (score 0):

I like my dropdowns to stay open even if they're not being hovered on so I do something that's a little cheeky.

I use buttons and the :focus selector to keep the menu open even if it's not being hovered over. There's of course other ways to do it, but check my jsfiddle for a very unrefined pure css example.

The most important bit I think would be the full (or almost full width). To do that just make sure your dropdown contents thing is inside your navbar and your navbar has a position set, such as "relative". Then your dropdown should have a position of absolute, a top of 100% (or something higher) and a left of 0 (or whatever).

Then make sure nothing between your drowndown or navbar has the position set and you should get a nice full width dropdown.

```css
.root, body, html{
  margin : 0px;
  padding : 0px;
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  background-color : blue;
  
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
}

.navbar{
  position : relative;
  height : 60px;
  width : 100%;
  background-color : white;
  
  display : flex;
  flex-direction : row;
  justify-content : center;

}

.dropdown{
  position : absolute;
    
  top : 105%;
  left : 0px;
  
  display : none;
  height : 200px;
  background-color : white;
  width : 100%;
}

.link:focus .dropdown{
  display : flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="navbar">
    <button class="link">
      <div class="text">Dropdown 1</div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        Content 1
      </div>
    </button><button class="link">
      <div class="text">Dropdown 2</div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        Content 2
      </div>
    </button><button class="link">
      <div class="text">Dropdown 3</div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        Content 3
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum and other such words
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the dropdown to hide when not actively using it because of all the products that are displayed behind the menu. Thanks for sharing though!